# Redirect parent from iFrame

Tags: html, iframe

How do I redirect my parent window once a URL is clicked in my iframe ?

Answer (score 4):

Setting a link's `target` property to `_top` will cause the link to open in the topmost frame; setting it to `_parent` will open it in the parent frame.

```
<a href="index.html" target="_parent">Open link in parent frame</a>
```

If that's not the correct answer, please clarify what you mean.